# CollectionView Multiple SectionsHeader Rows

Tags: swift

I have a collectionView inside this TableView. I added sectionHeader to CollectionView, but the same name appears in 2 rows. I did switch case but always case 0 works case 1 does not work. How can I use two different SectionHeader? 1st part 0.row 2nd part 1.row. I want the rows' sectionHeaders to be separate.

[Col Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgjTC.png)

```
extension denemeView: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return model[collectionView.tag].count

    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
   if (collectionView == collectionViewSıralama) {

           var reusableview = UICollectionReusableView()
            if (kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader) {
                let section = indexPath[indexPath.row]
               switch (section) {
               case 0:
                   if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader{
                                      let KatIsım : String = davetiyeKatIsım[collectionView.tag]

                                                                sectionHeader.sectionHeaderlabel.text = KatIsım


          let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
                                                                layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

                                                                            sectionHeader.sectionHeaderlabel.text = KatIsım
                                      reusableview = sectionHeader
                                                        }
               case 1:
                   if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "SectionHeader", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader{
                                      let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
                                                                layout?.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
                  let KatIsım : String = "davetiyeKatIsım2[0]"
                   sectionHeader.sectionHeaderlabel.text = KatIsım

                                  reusableview = sectionHeader
                                                    }
               default:
                   return reusableview

               }
           }
           return reusableview
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes I look at these code samples and truly hope that the indentation is some weird consequence of copying and pasting the code in.

Comment: I updated topics.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the implementation of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method, causing that number of sections is always 1 (in case you do not override the function, that is the default number), as result your switch always goes on number 1.

So, override the method `func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int` and it should work.